# What's the difference between base/uri/path/ etc in haproxy acl?

Tags: linux, proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy

haproxy acl based on

base
uri
path
query
url
capture.req.uri

what's the definition and difference?

for example, a `http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc?x=1&y=2`,
which part is base, uri, path, query, url, etc?

Answer (score 2):

- base - www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc
- uri - /aaa/bbb/ccc?x=1&y=2
- path - /aaa/bbb/ccc
- query - x=1&y=2

url - typicaly it's something like full http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc?x=1&y=2, but afaik haproxy doesn't use it.